# Retrieve records having same username but sequntially from parse server

Tags: android, parse-server

I am making an app which shows the image and text according the username
from parse database but,when I have two same username at that time 
i want to fetch complete single record and after that second record.
How to do that?

I am getting like this
    user_1->text + user_2->text,
    user_1->image + user_2->image

I want like this 
    user_1->text + user_1->image
    user_2->text + user_2->image

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOn5l.jpg)
code is given below

```
for (ParseObject object:objects){


                        s1=object.getString("message");
                        textView=new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                        // textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                          //      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                     //   textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

                        textView.setTextSize(25);
                        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textcolor));
                        textView.setText(s1);
                        l1.addView(textView);

                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)textView.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.setMargins(15,5,5,0);
                        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                        ParseFile file=(ParseFile)object.get("image");

                        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

                                if(e == null && data != null){
                                    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);

                                    ImageView imageView=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

                                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            1250
                                    ));

                                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    l1.addView(imageView);
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve? I saw that you have 2 records with the same username, each one of them have an image so you want to fetch both users or just one or what?

Comment: these are the steps I want to achieve...
1. text of first kishan
2. image of first kishan
3. text of second kishan
4. image of second kishan

Here please note that both kishan are same...he has two entry..@RanHassid